# UITableViewCell accessoryView overlap custom button of cell OR how to change accessoryView position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using [MSCellAccessory](http://github.com/bitmapdata/MSCellAccessory) to set custom colour to accessoryView. It worked fine. But when I place button in cell and click on cell, checkmark is visible but it overlaps delete button. Check my snap shot.[image: In this image I set border to accessory view. It appear on delete. So I cannot press delete button.]

So how to change cell accessoryView position in UITableViewCell or set accessoryView below delete button.

Comment: Make your own UITableViewCell subclass

Answer (score 1):

If you are sub-classing the UITableViewCell you can adjust it in layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect accessoryViewFrame = self.accessoryView.frame;
    accessoryViewFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(accessoryViewFrame);
    self.accessoryView.frame = accessoryViewFrame;
}
```

OTHERWISE......
Add a subview instead of accessoryView

```
UIButton *indicatorBtn = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
indicatorBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-55, 2, 50, 50);
[indicatorBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_indicator.png"] 
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
indicatorBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//indicatorBtn.alpha = 0.5;
indicatorBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[indicatorBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:indicatorBtn];
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved by adding UIImageView for tick. And put beside the delete button, and it works for me. I am not using table cell accessory. Please check below code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
CGRect cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableViewSavedSearch.frame), tableViewSavedSearch.rowHeight);
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
cell.frame = cellRectangle;
CGFloat imageWidth = 30;

//Name
UILabel *lblName = [DesignModel createPaddingLabel:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cellRectangle) - (imageWidth * 2), tableViewSavedSearch.rowHeight) labelTag:TAG_SAVED_SEARCH_NAME textColor:COLOUR_BLUE_DARK textAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft textFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_CENTURY_GOTHIC size:14] padding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];

//Delete button
UIButton *button = [DesignModel createImageButton:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(lblName.frame), 0, imageWidth, tableViewSavedSearch.rowHeight) image:imageDelete tag:TAG_SAVED_SEARCH_DALETE];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSaveAndSearch_DeleteAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

//TICK
UIImageView *imageView = [DesignModel createImageView:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame), 0, imageWidth, tableViewSavedSearch.rowHeight) image:imageTick tag:TAG_SAVED_SEARCH_TICK contentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

return cell;
}
```